# How pass an ElementModel to a Macro in Twig

Tags: templating, macro

I'm trying to pass an AssetModel into a twig macro but all I'm getting is:

```
Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string
```

Is there any way to define my twig macro variable to be an object instead of a string?

This is my macro

```
{% macro item(thumbnail) %}
    {% if thumbnail %}
        <img src="{{ thumbnail }}"/>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

This is my template

```
{% import "macros/grid.html" as grid %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('handle') %}
    {{ grid.item(entry.image) }}
{% endfor %}
```

*entry.image* is an Asset field

Comment: Can you share your code, so we can see it in context?

Comment: code added Douglas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems. The first is that `{{ grid.item(entry.image) }}` is actually an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) (i.e. which behaves like an array of images) and not an ElementModel (i.e. a single image), even if only one image is defined. To get the first image you can use `entry.image.first` or `entry.image[0]`.

The second problem is that in your macro, `<img src="{{ thumbnail }}"/>` is trying to set the url string using the whole `ElementModel` (or in your case the ElementCriteriaModel). Instead use: `{{ thumbnail.url }}`

```
{% macro item(thumbnail) %}
    {% if thumbnail %}
        <img src="{{ thumbnail.url }}"/>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import item %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('handle') %}
    {{ item(entry.image.first) }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:** If on the other hand, for some reason you want to pass the ElementCriteriaModel then you just need to handle it appropriately in the macro:

```
{% macro item(thumbnail) %}
    {% if thumbnail.first %}
        <img src="{{ thumbnail.first.url }}"/>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import item %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('handle') %}
    {{ item(entry.image) }}
{% endfor %}
```

As a side note — keep in mind that the macro can also exist in the same template and imported using `_self`.

Comment: Thing is I would like to make the check if there's any image select in my macro to keep the code of my template more clean. So I would like to pass the entire ElementCriteriaModel into my macro and in there run my *if model|length > 0* to get any image selected. Possible?

Comment: I would like to do this since I'm reusing my macro across multiple templates. Maybe that's bad practice?

Comment: @naboo Id say it's no bad practice at all to import macros, but I can also imagine that importing many files could indeed increase load time. What I do is to put my macros all in one file "includes/macros.html" that I import from my base template "_layout.html". On the other hand, I read somewhere that Twig does `extends` and `include` very performant and `import` is maybe not that different.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant the practice of passing an ElementCriteriaModel to my macro and within the macro making the check if there's an image present or not :)

Comment: ... also importing the macro at the top of the template and reusing it further down... will that increase page load? Isn't the import only made once?

Comment: @naboo to help you with your problem: you could try and feed your macro an array of element models instead of that elementcriteriamodel, by adding `find()`. Additionally it is always good to use the plural with your vars or fieldnames if there's multiple elements: `{{ grid.item(entry.images.find()) }}` :)

Comment: The user can only select one image, so the naming should be fine. Regarding my original question I'm taking it that passing the entire "ElementCriteriaModel" isn't doable. I can only pass the "ElementModel"?

Comment: Ouups... no you can always have your macro output nothing, I don't see any bad practice there. And yes, if you don't call the import multiple times, say with a loop :)

Comment: It's not what the user selects, but how Craft returns request. It's always multiple images and you have to use `first()` to get the one selected. Did `find()` do the trick?

Comment: To better understand what I mean with an array of element models read here about the difference to ecm: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#find

Comment: You can pass anything you want to the macro, including ElementCriteriaModel. You just need to handle it correctly in the macro. So, instead the macro would be `{% if thumbnail.first %}<img src="{{ thumbnail.first.url }}">{% endif %}`. I only mentioned the macro import thing because this was such a simple macro and could easily be inline vs a macro at all. By all means, import your macros! That's what it's there for.

Comment: Ah Douglas - right on. It's not the macro complaining, it's the code _WITHIN_ the macro. I didn't realize this at first, now I see what's wrong. Thank you for pointing this out! :)

Comment: @naboovalley if this correct, can you hit the checkmark? This will help others. Thanks.